# Start cmd-scripts sequentually at system startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have Windows 2012 system with some servers. Every server starts with batch script, and some servers depends on another.

I need to start these scripts sequentially.
I have 4 cmd files: startMasterServer.cmd, startSlaveServer1.cmd, startSlaveServer2, startAnotherUtility.cmd.

Slave servers can start only after master server. But when I execute startMasterServer.cmd, it need 1-2 minutes to start. Another utility don't need anything for it, it can be started at any time.

How to manage autostart of servers in Window 2012? Maybe start scripts with timeouts or something???

And how to start my batch script when OS starts? No any user logged in at this time.

Comment: Do you have any chance to recognize from another server if the "master-server" has completed its startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maby you can use `timeout 5` this for example will wait 5 seconds before continue the script.

So in your case you might want to use the following:

> startMasterServer.cmd
>   timeout 120
>   startSlaveServer1.cmd
>   timeout 120
>   startSlaveServer2.cmd
>   timout 120
>   startAnotherUtility.cmd

Comment: Thanks! I found some solution, I used "start cmdFilePath.cmd", and it starts script in another window, and used timeout. But now I don't know, how to start this script at startup, with no logged user.

Comment: you can create an automated task - declare to start on "Startup"

Comment: Yes! I made it with Windows Task Scheduler, started task from all users with all privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Make another script that start the others scripts, placing timeouts between them.

Something like this:

```
@echo off
script1.cmd
timeout 120
script2.cmd
timeout 120
....
```

Then start only this script, and let it do the rest of the work.

Comment: i think you dont got the question - the scripts have to run on different servers

Comment: No. script runs on one machine, but every process - is server. All of them are on one computer.